# Django add or update dates in database

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to create a form with some features :
if GTIN isn't already used -> create a new product in my database
else if GTIN already used -> update dateExpiry corresponding to this GTIN in my database

my code is the following one:

**form.py:**

```
class productForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['GTIN', 'name', 'price', 'expiryDate']
```

**views.py:**

```
 def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = productForm(request.POST).save()
        return redirect('/cbPlus')
    else :
        form = productForm()

    template = loader.get_template('cbPlus/index.html')
    product = Product.objects.order_by('expiryDate')
    context = {
        'product' : product,
        'form' : form
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request=request))
```

**models.py:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
   GTIN = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
   price = models.FloatField(max_length=25)
   expiryDate = models.DateTimeField(max_length=25)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no question in the text, so I'm guessing you want help regarding creating a product from the form. You need to put something like this in POST if.

```
form = productForm(request.POST)
if not form.is_valid():
    ... # Handle form errors here
product = form.save(commit=False)
old_product = Product.objecte.filter(GTIN=product.GTIN).first()
if old_product:
    old_product.expiryDate = product.expiryDate
    old_product.save()
else:
    product.save()

return redirect('/cbPlus')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you would like your POST to either handle a new Product or an updated Product.

Here is what I would do, using some pseudo code:

```
if request.method = "POST":
    if not Product.objects.filter(GTIN=request.GTIN).exists():
          new_product = Product(request.GTIN, ...)
          new_product.save()
    else:
        update_product = Product.objects.filter(GTIN=request.GTIN)
        update_product.name = request.name
        #update the remaining fields...
        update_product.save()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks you, but now I v got this exception : 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'GTIN', do you have an idea ?

Comment: Use `request.POST['GTIN']` instead of `request.GTIN`

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should put `create` and `update` in separate views. `update` retrieves the already saved object using its primary_key which should be passed to the view. But in your case, you can do the following:

```
def index(request):
    product = Product.objects.filter(GTIN=request.POST['GTIN']).first()
    if product:
        # update
        form = productForm(request.POST, instance=product)
    else:
        # create
        form = productForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')  # Usually redirect after object create or update
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: 'too many values to unpack (expected 2) ' : do you Know how to solve this exception ?

Comment: I need to see more of the traceback. Can you post more of the error?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my code, I just updated it. Please try the updated version. Put `GTIN=` in filter.

Comment: exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value: 'GTIN'                                                                                                    product = Product.objects.filter(request.POST['GTIN']).first()